# Invoking a FlowLayoutPanel, preventing UI from freezing while items are added

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous

Basically i'm trying to populate a flow layout panel with user controls all whilst the UI is still reponsive.

I'm building a server/client application which gets rss feeds and then returns articles. I want to populate the flowlayoutpanel with these articles whilst the UI is still responsive.

At the moment i've tried something like so:

```
            Subc(feedcodes); //this method sends codes to the server and gets responses.
            if (NewsItemsPanel.InvokeRequired)
            {
                NewsItemsPanel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => popPanel()));
                //popPanel populates the panel with the news items;

            }
```

at the moment the if/else never executes the if. I've tried searching around but couldn't find relevant or near relevant help. The above code is inside a button click.

This is the popPanel method:

```
    private void popPanel()
    {
        try
        {
            feedsPanel.Controls.Clear();
            foreach (NewsItem item in News.getNewsItems())
            {
                usercontrolNewsItem rssitem = new usercontrolNewsItem (item.title, item.summary);
                feedsPanel.Controls.Add(rssitem);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
```

any help would be great :)

thanks

Comment: How many items are in the results?  Are you sure that you already have a materialized result set when you invoke to the UI thread and that execution is not deferred?

Comment: There's a serious bug in your code, you cannot use Controls.Clear() like that.  Removed controls *must* be disposed.  As written, the code will slow down a lot and eventually crash.  Never add more than, at most, 50 controls to a panel.

Answer (score 0):

When you click a button, its event rises in the UI thread => no `InvokeRequired`. Your *long running code* should be executed outside of UI thread, from where you invoke back to UI thread, when updating something.

To example,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel.Clear(); // *see Hans comment
    (new Thread(LongRunningMethod)).Start();
}

private void LongRunningMethod()
{
    // ... retrieve items

    Invoke(() =>
    {
        // ... add items to panel
    });
}
```

however, I'd recommend this design

```
private void LongRunningMethod()
{
    while(thereAreMoreItems)
    {
        // ... retrieve next item

        Invoke(() =>
        {
            // ... add item to panel
        });
    }
}
```

If there are many of items, then you better use one *list control in virtual mode*. Creating hundreds of controls are bad. Loading million items of data, if user only look at hundred at max at once, is bad.